# How to access elements of a stream in Java 8, or return one element of a stream?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I have the method:

```
public Monitor getCurrentMonitor() {
    findCurrentMonitor();
    return monitors.stream().filter(a -> a.isCurrent());
}
```

It's purpose is to find the current Monitor (there is only one in the list), and return it. How would I accomplish this functionally, or would it be better to do it procedurally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `findFirst()`, which will return an `Optional<Monitor>`, then you just return the value in this `Optional` instance or you throw an exception if it's empty (as you said there is a current monitor in the list):

```
public Monitor getCurrentMonitor() {
    return monitors.stream()
                   .filter(a -> a.isCurrent())
                   .findFirst()
                   .orElseThrow(() -> new NoCurrentMonitorException());
}
```

The `orElseThrow` part is to prevent calling `get` on an empty `Optional` (it might be better to throw your custom exception in this case to make the intent clear that there is no current monitor instance in the list).

---

I'm not sure what your `findCurrentMonitor();` is doing. I guess you should just remove it as the filtering on the stream is basically what it does; i.e finding the current monitor. From a pure functionnal aspect you shouldn't call this function (`findCurrentMonitor();`) as it have side effects.

Comment: @Connorelsea Simply a container which may contain a value. You might want to check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Comment: This is my code to show you what findMonitor does. It also includes my solution to the problem, based off of your solution, without having to throw around annoying exceptions: http://pastebin.com/ZVKqA2Yz

Comment: @Connorelsea Well, for a purely functional manner, you shouldn't have function that modify the data in place. I.e, your methods should not have side-effects (so not have a void return type). They should "communicate" with the external environment only by taking arguments and returning results (think about the Java's String class). So strictly speaking about your `findCurrentMonitor` function, it should return a new List from which each element would have been created via a copy constructor and on which you set their `current` property; so that the original data is not mutated.

Comment: Is it practical to apply purely functional concepts in Java. This would change the entire way I program. For example, view the entire class please: http://pastebin.com/N42v4apg

Comment: Should all methods never have a void return type? This seems a little crazy to implement in Java. I can't imagine it.

Comment: @Connorelsea No, Java isn't a functional language so it's harder to deal with this "side-effect" property has you would do with a functional one (such as Scala). If you get the main idea; it's fine but as you said it would be harder (not impossible) to implement it in a functional way.

Comment: Is it wrong to use functional concepts such as lambdas in Java without having a fully functional program? Both times I have asked questions about lambdas, people have suggested a "completely-functional" refactoring of my code, which seems kind of insane. Should I stick to procedural loops? Is it wrong to mix the paradigms?

Comment: @Connorelsea There are cases that procedural loops are more convenient that using the Stream API and all its tools. No it's not wrong to use functional concepts; even sometimes you have to write some Scala code into a procedural way (though it's recommended to do it unless you really don't have the choice). Really I would say it depends on the use-case you are facing. As I said, even with the brand new features in Java 8, it's still a procedural language.

Comment: Mixing approaches, though, can lead to awkward or buggy code, e.g. mutating state from a lambda being run over a stream.

Comment: @AlexisC. I know that's an old answer but just had one thing I didn't quite get. As you said, to get a value from the `Optional<Object>`, we have to call `.get()`. You also said that you call `orElseThrow` to prevent calling `get()` but I am not sure how that work **without** using `get()`. Is `orElseThrow` expected to behave like `get()` if it finds `Optional<>` is not empty? I would expect it to look something like this: `.findFirst().get().orElseThrow(...)`. That won't work of course but that looks more logical to me. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @EugeneS Yes, `orElseThrow` will give you the value if its in the `Optional` otherwise it'll throw an exception (the one you give as parameter with the supplier). See the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Optional.java#Optional.orElseThrow%28java.util.function.Supplier%29).

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification and the reference.